# How to add new Element with unique name and delete specific element

Tags: jquery, click, appendto

```
$(function(){
   $("#getitem").click(function(){
    var txtval = $("#txt").val();
    var number = ?????
    $('<input type="text" name=txt"'+number+'" value="'+txtval+'" />').appendTo('#form');
   });
});
```

Good Day,

Im having trouble solving this one, Basically I'm stuck. All I just need is create a new input type with a unique name preferably incremented numbers. then I have a function that can delete specific new element.. Hope you guys can help me.. Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var namecounter = 0;
    $("#getitem").click(function() {
        namecounter++;
        var txtval = $("#txt").val();
        $('<input type="text" name="txt' + namecounter + '" value="' + txtval + '" />').appendTo('#form');
    });
})
```

Now the inputs get generated with name as txt1, txt2, ...

Comment: var i = $('.myClassName').size() + 1    then I will add class to the element.. are they the same? which you recommend?